# command to validate input in a pipeline then pass it on?

Tags: shell, perl, pipe, pipeline

I want to inject a command into a pipeline that just validates the input at that point, passing it on if it's valid.  If it isn't valid nothing could be passed on, or perhaps a custom-defined error message from an option or something.

At the moment I'm using perl for this as in this example where I check for an expected
unique match for $1 in a file:

```
  grep -P '^\s*\Q$(strip $1)\E\s+' file_codes.txt             \
  | perl -e '@in = <STDIN>;'                                  \
         -e '@in == 1 or die "wrong number of matches";'      \
         -e 'print @in'                                       \
  | xargs                                                     \ 
  | ...
```

I don't like this because it seems both un-pipeish and un-perlish with the explicit read and print involving @in.  It seems like there out to be something like tee or so that does it but I didn't find it.

Comment: Why would you use perl for this at all? It seems like something native bash is just as suited for.

Comment: ...that said, I assume it's by intent that `$(strip $1)` is in a single-quoted context, so it isn't actually getting run as a command? (If it _was_ to be run as a command, you'd also want to fix the unquoted expansion of `$1`, in addition to moving it from a single-quoted context to a double-quoted one).

Comment: Sometimes streaming isn't the proper way to deal with user input.

Comment: It might make this easier to answer if you described more about what you're actually trying to accomplish and the constraints that led to this solution, to allow suggestion of different approaches to fulfill that goal within the constraints at hand.

Comment: Can you add a concrete example?  What you want to do really isn't clear here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  well good as the answers here are in perl terms you're right in that I sort of want something more general, i.e. set -o pipefail && first_command | (syntax_or_prefix_command_that_run_validation_command_and_passes_input_along) | more_commands.  I want something like tee that forks the stdin off to a file also, but I instead want it just run a validation command with usual exit code interpretation and preferably output nothing on fail or exactly it's input on success.  Annoyingly I feel like I came up with a way to do this at some point then forgot it again :(

Answer (score 3):

```sh
grep ... |
perl -e'
   defined($line = <>) && !defined(<>)
      or die("Wrong number of matches\n");
   print $line;
' |
xargs ...
```

The Perl program outputs a line to STDOUT if and only if there's only one line of input. If there isn't exactly one line of input, it outputs nothing to STDOUT and an error message to STDERR.

The Perl program reads as little as possible. This mean that both `perl` and `grep` might end earlier and thus less use CPU and disk.

The line breaks inside and outside of the Perl program can be left in or removed.

Answer (score 2):

Test the current input line number, `$.` (note that it should be exactly 1, so it is tested twice):

```
% echo foo | perl -pe 'die "wrong number of matches" if $. > 1; END { die "wrong number of matches" if $. < 1; }' | xargs
foo

% echo "foo\nbar" | perl -pe 'die "wrong number of matches" if $. > 1; END { die "wrong number of matches" if $. < 1; }' | xargs
wrong number of matches at -e line 1, <> line 2.
foo

% cat /dev/null | perl -pe 'die "wrong number of matches" if $. > 1; END { die "wrong number of matches" if $. < 1; }' | xargs
wrong number of matches at -e line 1.
END failed--call queue aborted.
```